# How to trace a users actions?

Tags: 2007, workflow, tasks

Is there any way to find out if a user tried to complete a task?

Scenario:

We have a custom approval workflow (SP Designer). Each user updates a document, then completes a task. Pretty straight forward. However, we suspect that users are trying to get around the process because they do not want to be a part of an audit trail. Instead, they will claim that they tried to complete the task, "but SharePoint wouldn't let them". They then forward the doc to us, hence going outside the process.

Is there any way to see if a user tried to complete a task and was denied (for whatever reason)?

Answer (score 2):

You can write log to "Workflow History" List, on task completion/ whatever action you want to trace.
by default this list is hidden, you can view it by http://server.domain.tld/lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx.